# Why is my Bank Management System not working properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, object

So, I am making this bank management system in c++ where I will have to give the user an option to create an account, deposit the money, withdraw it, and display the details. I also need to store in the array of objects so that the entire data can be displayed after the user exits. The restrictions are that I cannot use file handling. But it isn't working properly.

Please help.

When I run it, it keeps asking me for full name. How do I resolve this issue?
I feel like this issue is occurring because of the persons array of type bankaccount, but I don't see any other possible way to do this.
I have deleted the details of some functions because it became a lengthy block of code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <time.h>  
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class bankaccount {
private:
    int id;
    string name;
    int cash;
    int money;
    int age;
public:
    string get_name() {
        return name;
    }
    int get_id() {
        return id;
    }
    void withdraw();
    void deposit();
    int see_money();
    bankaccount(int id1) {
        id = id1;

        cout << "\n Enter Full Name:";
        getline(cin, name);

    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const bankaccount& d);




};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, bankaccount& d) {
    os << "\n Your name is:" << d.get_name();
    os << "\n Your id is:" << d.get_id();
    os << "\n You have a total of : " << d.see_money();
}
int main() {
    bankaccount persons[100] = 0;
    int option;
    int id;
    int number = 0;
    cout << "BANKING MANAGEMENT SYSTEM!" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    while (1) {

        cout << "\nEnter 1 to create an account. Enter 2 to deposit money. Enter 3 to withdraw money. Enter 4 to check money. Enter 5 to display. Enter 6 to exit";
        cin >> option;
        switch (option) {
        case 1: {

            bankaccount p(number);
            persons[number] = p;

            cout << "Your ID is:" << number << endl;
            number++;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "\n Enter Your ID:";
            cin >> number;


            persons[number].deposit();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            cout << "\n Enter Your ID:";
            cin >> number;
            persons[number].withdraw();
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            cout << "\n Enter Your ID:";
            cin >> number;
            persons[number].see_money();
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            cout << "\n Enter Your ID:";
            cin >> number;
            cout << persons[number];
            break;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the output:]

Comment: A debugger should let you see the call stack which would go a long way to explaining what is happening.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `std::vector`?

Comment: No, we can't use that too :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't restricted the use of pointers or you don't *have* to specifically store it in a static array you can try this. You can create an array of bankaccount type pointers. In this case an array of 100 pointers. Each pointer will point to a separate object of bankaccount. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR0l1.jpg for a better visual understanding.

You can create it like this:

```
bankaccount* persons[100];
```

So in case 1, when you create a new account and add it to the array you can do this:

```
persons[number] = new bankaccount();
number++;
```

This way you won't have to change your constructor. Just a cool way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

`bankaccount persons[100]=0;`

Here you construct 100 objects of your `bankaccount`.

Your `bankaccount` constructor has these 2 lines:

```
cout<<"\n Enter Full Name:";
getline(cin,name);
```

So each time you create a `bankaccount` object, you're prompted for its name. You probably didn't intend that. You need to de-couple this, so asking the user for the Full Name, assigning it to a bankaccount, and constructing a bankaccount object are separate.

e.g. you can create option 6 to assign a name to the bankaccount instead of doing it inside the constructor of your `bankaccount` class.

Comment: You may want to mention that `bankaccount persons[100]=0;` is not legal code and wont compile in modern compilers.